# Magento Checkout Progress is empty

Tags: php, ajax, magento, magento-1.9, warehouse

I asked everywhere. I wrote a mail to the developers, who selled the extension. (Innoexts Warehouse). But no one could give me an answer!

I have installed this extension. First it worked great. Then i updated the webshop to 1.9.2.1. and the progress doesn't worked anymore...

It's an ajax request, when you go to next step. If you do that, it will load new checkout progress in sidebar, but the returnvalue of the ajax request is empty. When i run the page, it's empty.

What's wrong with this extension!?

Comment: deactivate the plugin and try. if it works then contact with plugin developers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

1. Take backup of db and files.
2. reinstall extension
3. enable compilation
4. Flush all cache and reindex all

Just try if work.if you still get same problem then disable extension and check again.

Comment: I found the failure:

It's in the core... -.-